# How create trigger for cycle absence control (Oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I create so

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_CONTROL_ABSENCE_CYCLE
BEFORE UPDATE ON DEPARTMENT
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN (
    SELECT D.ID, D.ID_PARENT
    FROM DEPARTMENT D
    START WITH D.ID_PARENT = :NEW.ID
    CONNECT BY PRIOR D.ID = D.ID_PARENT
  )
  LOOP
    IF :NEW.ID_PARENT = REC.ID THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cycle in hierarchies detected');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Gives an error message
[42000][4098] ORA-04098: trigger invalid and caused a crash when validating

(I do not know English, so I translated it through a translator)

Comment: you cannot able to create it ? can you see it in `select * from user_errors` ? what is the error ? try to drop it and create it

Comment: Is everything spelled correctly?  I want to understand correctly whether I create a trigger

Comment: You might be missing a comma: REFERENCING NEW AS NEW, OLD AS OLD.

Comment: You can't query the same table that's associated with the trigger. for that, you need to create Compound triggers. But this error would only arise when the trigger would be fired, not created.As @Rene wrote, you might be missing a comma. But you will still have the problem I mentioned.

Comment: You can skip the `REFERENCING` clause if you're not referencing `new` or `old` as anything different.